# TABLES With Same Column Name

Tags: sql-server

I have 10 tables and each table have 10 columns with similar Name. Tables have some other column too with dissimilar Name so is there anyway to write
   SELECT query so that i do not have to repeatedly write column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using MySQL, you can select all columns in table by using the '*' selector:

```
 SELECT table1.*, table2.*, table3.* .....
```

Also, you can use 'AS' to define each column:

```
 SELECT table1.column1 AS column11, table1.column2 AS column12, table2.column1 AS column21 .....
```

Comment: Tables have some other column too with dissimilar Name

Comment: @Yogesh there isn't a way to append the name in front of some and not others automatically - it'll be one or the other unfortunately

Comment: @Prescott I was curious so asked ..may be later things like this will come into picture